# не закрывается scanner

Tags: java, scanner

Хочу закрыть свой `Scanner`, если впишу слово `Stop`

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
String[] words1 = new String[25];

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    if (sc.nextLine().equals("Stop")) {
        System.exit(0);         
    } else {
    words1[i]=sc.nextLine();
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < words1.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(words1[i]+" ");
}
```

Но не получается. Ввод данных продолжается, если вписываю Stop. + не выводится массив.

Comment: так же. ввод продолжается

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести. Ввод останавливается на «Stop». Распишите подробнее: как запускаете, что именно вводите. А то что массив не печатается, так это потому что Вы на «Stop» закрываете виртуальную машину. Нужно вместо этого выходить из цикла (`break;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема скорее всего в том, что вы используете `==` для сравнения слов, а `Java` по `==` сравниваются ссылки, используйте `sc.nextLine().equals("Stop")`

Вот полностью рабочий код

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] words1 = new String[25];
    for (int i = 0; i < 25 && sc.hasNextLine(); i++) {
        String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
        if (nextLine.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
            break;
        }
        words1[i] = nextLine;
    }
    for (String aWords1 : words1) {
        System.out.print(aWords1 + " ");
    }
```

Первая проблема которая у вас была, это то, что вы делали итерации не смотря на то, что строчки уже закончились. Поправлено добавлением `&& sc.hasNextLine()`.

Вторая проблема была в том, что Вы писали так

```
   if (sc.nextLine().equals("Stop")) {
        System.exit(0); 

    }
    else{
    words1[i]=sc.nextLine();
```

Вы два раза вызывали `nextLine`, первый раз строка была, а второй раз уже нет, потому что `nextLine` не возвращает постоянно одно и тоже значение в одной итерации, это не идемпотентный метод.

Ну и еще одна проблема была в том, что Вы вызвали `System.exit(0)`, если встретили слово `stop`, а это завершает выполнение `jvm`, и Вы никогда бы не дошли до цикла который выводит значения массива

Дополнительно. У Scanner вызывать метод `close` нельзя когда Вы передаете ему `System.in`, потому что он закрывает поток который ему передали и таким образом вы можете случайно закрыть `System.in`, а потом долго искать ошибку

Comment: да получилось . но когда я пытаюсь после этого вывести массив (через цикл) на экран случается та же проблема - ввод продолжается + массив не выводится.   `Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        String[] words1 = new String[25] ;
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            if (sc.nextLine().equals("Stop")) {
                System.exit(0); 
               
            }
            else{
            words1[i]=sc.nextLine();
        }}
        for (int i = 0; i < words1.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(words1[i]+" ");
        }`

Comment: Покажите как выводите, вместе с кодом наполнения массива, а то не совсем понимаю

Comment: поправил код в главном вопросе

Comment: Сейчас запущу Ваш код

Comment: Я обновил ответ, можете попробовать запустить код